# given derivative to get the original function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb R^n → \mathbb R^m$ be a differentiable function such that
$f (\mathbf 0) = \mathbf 0$ and $D f (\mathbf x)(\mathbf h) = 2⟨\mathbf x, \mathbf h⟩$ for any $\mathbf x, \mathbf h ∈ \mathbb R^n$.
Show that $f (\mathbf x) = ⟨\mathbf x, \mathbf x⟩$.

How should I use the theorem that $f : U ⊆ \mathbb R^n → \mathbb R^m$ with $U$ open and connected. If $D f (\mathbf x) = O$ for every $x ∈ U$, then $f$ is constant to prove this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: consider $h(x) = f(x) - \langle x, x \rangle$ and show that $Dh(x) = 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Ok I understand that if $\mathbf x=\mathbf 0$, then $h(\mathbf x)=0$, but how can I show the case when $\mathbf x\neq \mathbf 0$?

Comment: Take the derivative of $\langle x, x \rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $m=1$ in your question.

As a linear map, the matrix of $Df (\mathbf x) $ is $(2x_1,\ldots,2x_n) $. Thus $D_jf (\mathbf x)=2x_j $, and this forces  $f (\mathbf x)=x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2+c $. But $c=0$ by the condition at the origin.